# Find and replace in AIX 5.3

Tags: file, replace, sed, grep, aix

I am running AIX 5.3.
I have two flat text files.

- One is a "master" list of network devices, along with their communication settings(`CLLIFile.tbl`).
- The other is a list of specific network devices that need to have one setting changed, within the main file(specifically, `cn` to `le`). The list file is called `DDM2000-030215.txt`.

I have gotten as far as looping through `DDM2000-030215.txt`, pulling the lines I need to change with grep from `CLLIFile.tbl`, changing `cn` to `le` with sed, and sending the output to a file.

The trouble is, all I get are the changed lines. I need to make the changes inside `CLLIFile.tbl`, because I cannot disturb the formatting or structure.

Here's what we tried, so far:

```
for i in 'DDM2000-030215.txt'
do
grep -p $ii CLLIFile.tbl| sed s/cn/le/g >> CLLIFileNew.tbl
done
```

Basically, I need to replace all instances of 'le' with 'cn', within 'CLLIFile.tbl', that are on lines that contain a network element name from 'DDM2000-030215.txt'.

Comment: edit  your question to include sample input, your expected output, the code you are currently running, exact error messages. Use 4 spaces at the front of each line to have it appear "as-is" in your posting, to avoid auto-formatting provided by S.O. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Entirely new question, I see. For this, I would use awk:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[++n] = $0; next } { for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { if($0 ~ a[i]) { gsub(/cn/, "le"); break } } print }' DDM2000-030215.txt  CLLIFile.txt
```

This works as follows:

```
NR == FNR {                   # when processing the first file
                              # (DDM2000-030215.txt)
  a[++n] = $0                 # remember the tokens. This assumes that every
                              # full line of the file is a search token.
  next                        # That is all.
}
{                             # when processing the second file (CLLIFile.tbl)
  for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {   # check all remembered tokens
    if($0 ~ a[i]) {           # if the line matches one
      gsub(/cn/, "le")        # replace cn with le
      break                   # and break out of the loop, because that only
                              # needs to be done once.
    }
  }
  print                       # print the line, whether it was changed or not.
}
```

Note that if the contents of `DDM2000-030215.txt` are to be interpreted as fixed strings rather than regexes, you should use `index($0, a[i])` instead of `$0 ~ a[i]` in the check.

Comment: I hope AIX 5.3 has a decent awk, then; it would be much saner for this than sed. See edit. tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your sed (on AIX) will not have an -i option (edit the input file),
and you do not want to use a temporary file.
You can try a here construction with vi:

```
vi CLLIFile.tbl >/dev/null <<END
:1,$ s/cn/le/g
:wq
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `grep` here, because, as you've observed, it only outputs the matching lines.  You want to just use `sed` and have it do the replacement only on the lines that match while passing the other lines through unchanged.

So instead of this:

```
 grep 'pattern' | sed 's/old/new/'
```

just do this:

```
sed '/pattern/s/old/new/'
```

You will have to send the output into a new file, and then move that new file into place to replace the old `CLLIfile.tbl`.  Something like this:

```
cp CLLIfile.tbl CLLIfile.tbl.bak # make a backup in case something goes awry
sed '/pattern/s/old/new/' CLLIfile.tbl >newclli && mv newclli CLLIfile.tbl
```